# Any way to find transmission number without taking the gear box out?

Tags: transmission, dacia, logan

I have a Dacia Logan late 2013 year model in the UK. Its clutch failed and it's at the mechanic currently.  He's asking me if I know the transmission number so that he wouldn't need to pull the gear box out first. He says it would make it easier for him to find required parts.

P.S. Before anyone asks, this is a mechanic I fully trust; he has worked on my cars for nearly 15 years now and I never ever had a single incident where he'd any work or order any parts that wouldn't really be required.

Comment: It has to be stamped/engraved into the outer housing somewhere. If it's dirty you may have better chances finding it after wiping down with a rag or cloth etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]

Here is an example of the location of the identification number stamped to a transmission. Hope that helps.